# Can ISIC Malformed packets be routed through an ILO or IDRAC Management port

Tags: linux, networking

ISIC generates random IPs so it is possible for malformed packets to be routed through the management port and out into the private and / or public network. If I disable the management port and use either ILO or IDRAC instead, is there anyway the random IPs could generate this traffic via the ILO / IDRAC IP access?  Keep in mind I am only referring to Dedicated ILO / IDRAC ports and not - shared.

Comment: This question is off-topic.  Professionals don't try sending malformed packets at their out of band management interfaces.

Comment: It's on-topic if he's trying to secure a production system from an attack... not sure what his intentions are though.

Comment: Is the concern around malicious or untrusted code running on the drac/ilo?

Answer (score 0):

iDRAC or iLO run isolated on another bios/memory than the host system. You can update the firmware and reboot an iDRAC while the server run. Any vulnerability got to come from the management network (not from inside the host).

With that in mind please be sure to use secure password to be sure no one upload a rogue firmware.

As noted by [Dell](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/b/techcenter/archive/2013/02/04/security-best-practices-for-dell-idrac):

> iDRAC prevents foreign software from running in a whitelist manner.
>   iDRAC firmware is packaged as a single binary “blob”. Only software in
>   that blob is allowed to run. The whitelist is simply the single rule:
>   only software in the blob can run.
>
> An attacker might attempt to circumvent this rule by creating “rogue
>   firmware” that looks like genuine Dell published firmware, but in fact
>   contains malicious code.
>
> Several best practices will prevent the introduction of rogue firmware
>   on the iDRAC:
>
> - Only obtain iDRAC firmware from Dell
> - Store the firmware in a place with restricted access
> - Only allow a firmware update to be initiated by an authorized user
> - Require that the authorized user only use a firmware package that was stored in the place with restricted access
>
> Note the following exceptions:
>
> - a malicious administrator could flash a rogue firmware
> - an administrator could be the victim of social engineering and be fooled into updating with non-authentic firmware
> - an administrator could have his credentials compromised

Of course it exist some DDOS for iLO or iDRAC, like told there;

> - Fixes an issue in the iLO 2 TCP/IP stack that could cause iLO 2 to stop  servicing a listening port after receiving a rogue TCP packet
>     with RST flag  set.

So for your answer if a rogue's firmware is used, then yes, anything can happen, else I just seen in the past DDOS attack against the integrated management interface, as it's a set of service in listening's mode.